# Synthesis of active chemical manganese dioxide (CMD) for primary alcohol oxidation

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, synthesis, theoretical-chemistry, organic-oxidation

This paper<sup>[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6147282/)</sup> uses chemical manganese dioxide (CMD) instead of activated manganese dioxide for mild alcohol oxidation. I'm looking for a route on how to synthesize active CMD. Could this work?

$$\ce{Mn2O7 + 3MnO → 5MnO2}$$
$$\ce{2KMnO4 + 3MnSO4 + 2H2O→ 5MnO2 + K2SO4 + 2H2SO4}$$

How to make chemically pure $\ce{MnO2}$ active for oxidation reactions?

**Reference**

1. Lulinski, Piotr et al. “Chemical Manganese Dioxide (CMD): its application to the oxidative iodination of benzene, halobenzenes and some deactivated arenes.” Molecules (Basel, Switzerland) vol. 9,7 595-601. 30 **Jun. 2004**, doi:[10.3390/90700595](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6147282/)

Comment: This preparation of active MnO2 from activated carbon and KMnO4 by Carpino (https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00836a091) may be of use.

Comment: Pyrolysis of Manganese carbonate at around 410C gives a very active form of MnO2 for use in oxidations

Comment: @Waylander that's convenient, I have access to a lot of manganese sulfate, but building something that could hold 410C for 6 hours would be a challenge.

Comment: My research centre used to have a muffle oven set up at around that temperature for drying mol. sieves and I used that.

Comment: Do not involve Mn2O7. It is a highly reactive and a dangerous oxidizer. It can violently explode and you won't have any control of the reaction. With that being said, check out this paper from 1968: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo01258a106

Comment: @NilayGhosh I really like this one, but I'd rather try it using dean stark and form an azeotrope with toluene/ethyl acetate or ethanol+methanol instead, why do they specifically use benzene?

Answer (score 3):

Your question *suggests* you did not access Leo Paquette's [*Encyclopedia of Organic Reagents*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Encyclopedia+of+Reagents+for+Organic+Synthesis%2C+14+Volume+Set%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470017548) (14 volumes, some schools have access to the electronic version [*eEROS*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/047084289X)), or its one-volume siblings *by topic*, e.g., [*Oxidizing and Reducing Agents*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Oxidizing+and+Reducing+Agents-p-9780471979265) (this one by Burke and Dannheiser).  These resources cover physical / chemical properties of frequently used reagents and briefly showcases a selection of typical applications.

Citing the entry about $\ce{MnO2}$ of the [former source](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/047084289X.rm021.pub4), one of the of early hints *preceding* the protocols to prepare $\ce{MnO2}$  states for example

> «It is worthy of note that the percentage water content strongly influences both the oxidizing power and the selectivity (oxidation
> of multifunctional molecules) of active $\ce{MnO2}$. Thus it is well
> known that the wet material (40–60% $\ce{H2O}$) obtained after filtration must be activated by drying (heating to $\pu{100–130 ^\circ{}C}$ for
> $\pu{12–24 h}$ or, better, at $\pu{125 ^\circ{}C}$ for $\pu{52 h}$). Indeed, an excess of water decreases the oxidation power since, according to
> the triphasic mechanism generally postulated, it would prevent
> the adsorption of the substrate to the oxidatively active polar
> site on the surface of $\ce{MnO2}$.»

The first of the six protocols presented is the basic one by Attenburrow (beside protocols under acidic conditions, by pyrolysis, coating silica gel with active / activated $\ce{MnO2}$, etc.) and reads as

> «A solution of $\ce{MnSO4 ⋅ 4 H2O}$ ($\pu{110 g}$) in $\ce{H2O}$ ($\pu{1.5 L}$) and a solution of $\ce{NaOH}$ (40%; $\pu{1.17 L}$) were added simultaneously during $\pu{1 h}$ to a hot stirred solution of $\ce{KMnO4}$ ($\pu{960 g}$) in $\ce{H2O}$ ($\pu{6 L}$). $\ce{MnO2}$ precipitated soon after as a fine brown solid. Stirring was continued for an additional hour
> and the solid was then collected with a centrifuge and washed with water until the washings were colorless. The solid was dried in an oven at $\pu{100–120 ^\circ{}C}$ and ground to a fine powder ($\pu{960 g}$) before use.»

Probe which of the protocols works *well enough* for the application in question.  Since eEROS points to the primary literature which you may combine in a subsequent search in Reaxys, Science of Synthesis, SciFinder etc., you equally may see which of them are applied on substrates similar to yours.

**References**

Cahiez G.; Alami, M.; Taylor R. J. K.; Reid, M.; Foot, J. S.; Fader L.; Sikervar V.; Pabba, J. Manganese Dioxide *in* Encyclopedia of Reagents for Organic Synthesis; [doi 10.1002/047084289X.rm021.pub4](https://doi.org/10.1002/047084289X.rm021.pub4).

Attenburrow, J.; Cameron, A. F. B.; Chapman, J. H.; Evans, R. M.;
Hems, B. A.; Jansen, A. B. A.; Walker, T.. 194. A synthesis of vitamin A from *cyclo*hexanone. *J. Chem. Soc.* **1952**, 1094-1111; [doi 10.1039/JR9520001094](https://doi.org/10.1039/JR9520001094).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are looking for activated manganese dioxide (AMD). Apart from the Attenburrow process mentioned in @Buttonwood's answer ($\ce{MnSO4 + KMnO4 + NaOH}$), I found three other process that might suit your need (I noticed OP has loads of $\ce{MnSO4}$. So, the aforementioned process will work. The processes mentioned in this answer doesn't involve $\ce{MnSO4}$ so it can work as alternatives):

1. Rheological phase reaction method from manganese benzoate and $\ce{KMnO4}$ characterized by chemical titration ([Yuan et.al., **2003**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167577X02011096))
2. Potassium permanganate and manganese acetate, via a simple alternate drop-feeding method ([Han et.al., **2010**](https://ceramics.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1551-2916.2009.03567.x))
3. Using [decolorizing/activated charcoal](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Ebandik/organicweb/decolorcarbon.html) and aqueous potassium permanganate  to precipitate a brown-black powder presumably manganese dioxide mixed with carbon which can be separated using Buchner funnel ([Carpino, **1970**](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo00836a091))

Comment: The Attenburrow protocol only uses $\ce{MnSO4}$, water, $\ce{NaOH}$, and $\ce{KMnO4}$. Reading the entry by Cahiez *et al.* just again, *none* of the other five protocols adds sulfuric acid.  Even the second method *Preparation of Active $\ce{MnO2}$ from $\ce{KMnO4}$ under Acidic Conditions.* only reads as «Active $\ce{MnO2}$ was made by mixing hot solutions of $\ce{MnSO4}$ and $\ce{KMnO4}$, maintaining a slight excess of the latter for several hours, washing the product thoroughly with water and drying at $\pu{110–120 ^\circ{}C}$.»  Thus, your $+ \ce{H2SO4}$ might be a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Buttonwood Oops, I wrote H2SO4 instead of KMnO4. Fixed it.