# Differences in activated manganese dioxide synthesis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, theoretical-chemistry, organic-oxidation

I've looked into preparations of activated manganese dioxide for some time now, and what confused me is the contrast between the original Attenborough method and some of the alternatives.

> A solution of MnSO4⋅4H2O (110 g) in H2O (1.5 L) and a solution of NaOH
> (40%; 1.17 L) were added simultaneously during 1 h to a hot stirred
> solution of KMnO4 (960 g) in H2O (6 L). MnO2 precipitated soon after
> as a fine brown solid. Stirring was continued for an additional hour
> and the solid was then collected with a centrifuge and washed with
> water until the washings were colorless. The solid was dried in an
> oven at 100–120 ◦C and ground to a fine powder (960 g) before use.

That is molar ratio MnSO4.4H2O:KMnO4 - 1:8,34

> A solution of MnCl2⋅4H2O (200 g) in H2O (2 L) at 70 ◦C was gradually
> added during 10 min, with stirring, to a solution of KMnO4 (160 g) in
> H2O (2 L) at 60 ◦C in a hood. A vigorous reaction ensued with
> evolution of chlorine; the suspension was stirred for 2 h and kept
> overnight at rt. The precipitate was filtered off, washed thoroughly
> with H2O (4 L) until pH 6.5–7 and the washing gave a negligible
> chloride test. The filter cake was then dried at 120–130 ◦C for 18 h;
> this gave a chocolate-brown, amorphous powder; yield 195–200 g.

> Manganese (II) sulphate monohydrate (140 g) was dissolved in 2.66
> liters of water and heated to 60°C. Potassium permanganate (97.3 g) in
> 1.85 liter of water was added over a period of 15 minutes and stirred at 60°C for 1 hour, until manganese dioxide precipitated out. The
> reaction mixture was filtered and the residue was washed with
> deionised water until no sulphate ion was present. The solid was dried
> under suction for 2 hours followed by drying at 70°C under vacuum to a
> constant weight (about 8 days) to give 115 g of a dark brown powder

> In the span of 2h, to 250ml of 5% MnSO4 solution add 200ml of 5% KMnO4
> solution while stiring at 50-60C. Filter out the precipitate and wash
> until the absence of SO42- ions. Dry for 10h at 120C.

Whereas in these examples, it's more closer to 1:1. Why is that, will there be a difference in oxidative abilities? Alternatively, what would be the best way to synthesize this from Mn2+ salts?

**Refs.:**

Attenburrow, J.; Cameron, A. F. B.; Chapman, J. H.; Evans, R. M.; Hems, B. A.; Jansen, A. B. A.; Walker, T.. 194. A synthesis of vitamin A from cyclohexanone. J. Chem. Soc. 1952, 1094-1111; doi 10.1039/JR9520001094.

Galecki J. Preparatyka nieorganiczna. WNT; Warsaw: 1964. p. 439.

Comment: Duplicate?: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/154231/synthesis-of-active-chemical-manganese-dioxide-cmd-for-primary-alcohol-oxidati#comment317311_154231

Comment: @user55119 read more carefully "Whereas in these examples, it's more closer to 1:1. Why is that, will there be a difference in oxidative abilities? "